# Implement interface inside interface dynamically TS

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this typescript interface, that works as a **common structure** for api calls in my react app.

```
export interface ICommonApiState {
    loading: boolean;
    data: any;
    serverError: string;
}
```

As you can see, data type is any, but i want that type to be dynamic, because, i'm going to use this same interface in multiple places, but i don't want to create a new interface every time i use it, so, how can i pase a type to data depending on what i need ?

For example, if i'm making an api call to this server that will give me an array of user names, how can i pass that type to data using same interface ? Like..

```
const [userNames, setUserNames] = useState<ICommonApiState<IUserNames>>(
{
 loading: false,
 serverError: '',
 data: [] -> **This receives inferred types from IUserNames**
}
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One solution is to make it generic like below:

```
export interface ICommonApiState<T> {
    loading: boolean;
    data: T;
    serverError: string;
}
```

That way you are controlling what gets inferred in individual components that you are using.

You already have that example usage in your code: `ICommonApiState<IUserNames>`

Comment: Thank you, i'll give it a try, it seems quite basic, but i just didn't know how to do it );